# What kind of elements does $F\cup S$ contain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a subfield of the field $K$ and $S$ be a non-empty subset (not necessarily subfield) of $K$, finite or infinite.

What kind of elements does $F\cup S$ contain?

In my notes it says that $f(s_1, \ldots , s_n)\in F\cup S$, where $f\in F[x_1, \ldots , x_n]$ and $s_1, \ldots , s_n\in S$.

Why does this hold?

Comment: Maybe it meant to be $F(S)$ instead of $F \cup S$, or maybe it's a matter of notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The union of two sets contains exactly the things in one, or the other, or in both, sets.

The statement you've written is false: take $K=\mathbb{R}$, $F=\mathbb{Q}$, $S=\{\pi\}$, $f(x)=x+1$. Then $f\in F[x]$ and $\pi\in S$, but $f(\pi)=\pi+1\not\in F\cup S$.

Either you copied incorrectly, or there's a typo; I suspect that what is meant is that $f(s_1, . . . , s_n)$ is in the *subfield generated by* $F$ and $S$ - that is, the smallest subfield $G\subseteq K$ such that $F\cup S\subseteq G$. *It's a good exercise to show that there really **is** a smallest such $G$.* The statement is then true, and proving it is a good exercise.

Comment: Ah ok... I am looking at the following: Let $F(S)$ be the subset of $K$ that is defined as follows:  
An element $u\in K$ is in $F(S)$ iff there are finitely many elements of $S$, say $s_1, \dots , s_n$, and polynomials with $n$ variables $f,g\in F[x_1, \dots , x_n]$, with $g(s_1, \dots , s_n)\neq 0$, so that $u=f(s_1, \dots , s_n)/g(s_1, \dots , s_n)$. 
$$$$
We have that that $F(S)$ is a subfield of $K$. I want to show that it is even the smallest subfield of $K$, that contains $F$ and $S$. So, if $E$ is the subfield of $K$ and $F\cup S\subseteq E$, then $F(S)\subseteq E$.

Comment: In my notes there is the following solution: $$$$



Let $E$ a subfield of $K$ and $F\cup S\subseteq E$. 
The elements of $F(S)$ are of the form $\frac{f(s_1, \dots , s_n)}{g(s_1, \dots , s_n)}$. Since $F\cup S\subseteq E$ we have that $f(s_1, \dots , s_n)\in E$ and $g(s_1, \dots , s_n)\in E$. Since $E$ is a field we have that $\frac{f(s_1, \dots , s_n)}{g(s_1, \dots , s_n)}\in E$. Therefore, $F(S)\subseteq E$.

Comment: Is this solution correct? How does it follow then that $f(s_1, \dots , s_n)\in E$ and $g(s_1, \dots , s_n)\in E$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Yup, that's right! (Although note that your third-to-last sentence needs to invoke a property of $E$ - it's not true, e.g., if we replace $E$ by $F\cup S$ itself! Indeed, what's needed here is that $E$ is closed under addition and multiplication (which it is, being a subfield); do you see why?)

Comment: @MaryStar Try using the fact that $E$ is closed under addition and multiplication (since it is, after all, a field).

Comment: We have that $f(s_1, \ldots , s_n)$ is a linear combination of the elements $s_1, \ldots , s_n\in S$ and the coefficients are elements of $F$. Since $F\cup S\subseteq E$, we have that $F\subseteq  E$ and $S\subseteq E$. So, $s_i\in E$ and the coefficients $c_i\in E$. Since $E$ is a field we have that $ s_i^j\in E$, $c_js_i^j\in E$ and $\sum_{i,j} c_js_i^j\in E$. Therefore $f(s_1, \ldots , s_n)\in E$. Is this correct?